# Dropdown menu jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Well, I know I already asked something similar, but I'm desperate, I need to make this dropdown menu work. This is my code.

```
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-about"About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="dropdown-home" class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown-about" class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul class="dropdown-items">
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is that when I hover the cursor over the element with the class "nav-home", the element with the id "dropdown-home" is displayed with some effect. I tried it using jquery, but I'm just learning and I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Thank's.

Comment: Hi, get a look at Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But with this, the text will have to match the id .dropdown-[text]

```
 $('ul.menu-items li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
       $('div.dropdown-menu').hide();  
       $('div#dropdown-'+text).show();          
    });

    $('ul.menu-items li').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('div.dropdown-menu').hide();        
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XpaB7/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-items a').hover(function(){
    $('div[id&='+$(this).prop('class').split('-')[1]+']').show();
}, function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html). It's got built in [drop down](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns) [functionality](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) that should fit your needs.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.nav-home, .nav-about').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var cls = $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1];
        var id = '#dropdown-' + cls;
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
        $(id).show();
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8WKK/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    .menu-items, .menu-items a, .menu-items li {
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        list-style:none;
    }
    .menu-items li {
        min-width:150px;
    }
    .dropdown-items, .dropdown-items li {
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .dropdown-items {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="menu-items">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-home">Home</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-items">
                <li><a href="#">Something</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-about">About</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-items">
                <li><a href="#">Something</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.menu-items li').not(":animated").hover(

    function () {

        $(this).find(".dropdown-items").fadeIn(200)
    },

    function () {

        $(this).find(".dropdown-items").fadeOut(200)
    });
</script>
```